# Railstutorial #5 Section 3.4 Need of full_title helper. Help needed to understand the benefits

Tags: railstutorial.org

in  [Chapter 5 Section 3.4](http://rails-3-2.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-pretty_rspec) of the rails-3-2.railstutorial it says

> Of course, this is essentially a duplicate of the helper in Listing 4.2, but having two independent methods allows us to catch any typos in the base title. This is dubious design, though, and a better (slightly more advanced) approach, which tests the original full_title helper directly, appears in the exercises (Section 5.6).

I did as it said, but i do not understand the mentioned benefit

> ...having two independent methods allows us to catch any typos in the base title.

The "original" method in application_helper.rb and the test method in spec/support/utilities.rb act exactly the same. So from my point of view it´s a disvantage - there are two places to missspell.

I am new to ruby & rails and having a hard time cause the tutorial covers alot of new stuff, so please bear with me. I would be glad if someone could take some time to help me to understand.

Kind regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 1):

RSpec is a tool for testing.
So it's kind of check list that it "should" be.

If there is a typo one of two methods, the RSpec test will fail, so that you can notice there is something wrong there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, i still do not see the advantage of building redundance and test it instead of testing the actual method which will be used, in the first place. But okay i think its owed the fact that testing the real thing is a bit more complicated. Thanks for your answer.